# Apply CSS without particlular child column

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, ionic3

I need a small support here.You can see that

```
    .row1 {
        .col * {
            padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
        }
```

here it applies to all the child `col` elements.But I need to remove it from  `<ion-fab>` column. In other words, it should not be applied to this column

```
    <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-fab center middle>
          <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab>
      </ion-col>`
```

Can you tell me how to do that?

*.html*

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row class="row1">
      <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let d of data">
        <playlist [data]="d"></playlist>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-fab center middle>
          <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

*.scss*

```
.content {
        ion-grid {
            height: 40%;
        }
        .row1 {
            .col * {
                padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
            }
            flex: 1;
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
```

*Renderd content on the browser:*

```
<ion-grid class="grid" no-padding="">
    <ion-row class="row1 row">
      <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><ion-col class="col" col-6="">
        <playlist ng-reflect-data="[object Object]"><div class="playlist">
  <span>Just Added</span>
  <img src="./assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="Just Added">
</div></playlist>
      </ion-col><ion-col class="col" col-6="">
        <playlist ng-reflect-data="[object Object]"><div class="playlist">
  <span>My Favorites</span>
  <img src="./assets/images/img2.jpg" alt="My Favorites">
</div></playlist>
      </ion-col><ion-col class="col" col-6="">
        <playlist ng-reflect-data="[object Object]"><div class="playlist">
  <span>Presentation 1</span>
  <img src="./assets/images/img3.jpg" alt="Presentation 1">
</div></playlist>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="col" col-6="">
        <ion-fab center="" middle="">
          <button ion-fab="" mini="" class="fab fab-md"><ion-icon class="fab-close-icon icon icon-md ion-md-close" name="close" role="img" aria-label="close" ng-reflect-name="close"></ion-icon><span class="button-inner"><ion-icon name="add" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-md-add" aria-label="add" ng-reflect-name="add"></ion-icon></span><div class="button-effect"></div></button>
        </ion-fab>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

*Rendered Image:*

[image]

Comment: Is the content of _.html_ different when rendered? I.e. the selector `.col` applies to what?

Comment: Can't you just remove the asterisk from the selector in order to only apply the padding to the cells?

Comment: Please see the updated post @marekful

Comment: Then how can I apply the `padding` to other columns? This works under the `for loop`.Please see the updated post @HubertGrzeskowiak

Comment: is it the last column?

Comment: Yes,You're right @suraj

Comment: The simplest seems to me really to make that ion-col elem which will have the ion-fab inside have an additional class name, say .no-pad, and use `.col *:not(.no-pad)`

Comment: @Sampath as you can see every column gets the `col` class. Your selector, however, selects all elements that are descendants of those columns, but NOT the columns themselves. Just use `.col { ...` without the asterisk.

Comment: That is the support which I need.It works great.Hope you'll put it as an answer? @marekful

Comment: Since time immemorial, CSS has allowed this by means of specifying a second, more specific rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest seems to me really to make that `ion-col` element which will have the `ion-fab` inside have an additional class name, say `no-pad`, and change the selector to:

```
.col:not(.no-pad)
```